# ajax javascript - function and an ajax to validate content before upload to the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I have a button to upload content ( with key, size and md5 checksum ) to a server.
I don't know if that content could it be validate before content will be uploaded to the server???

Something like this is wrong I think.

```
function validateBefore(Key, mySize, md5CheckSum) {
    var valContent = {};
    valContent.Key = Key;
    if (mySize)
        valContent.mySize= mySize;
    if (md5CheckSum)
        valContent.md5CheckSum= md5CheckSum;
    $.ajax({
        ... ???????
    });
};
```

thanks

Comment: "I don't know if that content could it be validate before content will be uploaded to the server???"

Could you re-phrase this? It's not a question and it's hard to infer what your question is.

Comment: what is your problem. if you want to use ajax inside js function, it is fine since JQUERY is JS library.

Comment: Yes, it could be validated before upload to the server, but you will need something a little more complicated then that function unless you are using some sort of plugin, which it looks you are. But it MUST ALSO be validated on the server if it is coming from anything on the clientside, like javascript runing in a browser, as it only takes two minutes to bypass that validation for anyone with just a tiny bit of JS know how.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to validate a form or data on server side because client side validation can be prevented easily. If you want to validate on client side then prevent the form or data to be posted until its validation like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#some_form").submit(function(event) 
    {   
        key = $('#key').val()
        mySize = $('#mySize').val()
        md5CheckSum = $('#md5CheckSum').val()

        if( key == 'xyz' && mySize == 'xyz' && md5CheckSum == 'xyz' ) 
        {
            $.ajax({
                ... ???????
            });
        }
        else
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            //  SHOW ERROR IN HTML LIKE:    document.getElementById("error_key").innerHTML = 'some error';
        }        
    });    
});
```

Comment: Yes it is but that code you wrote will be easy to read by users. wont be best php code?